# How to fix 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text''

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape from
https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/hourly-weather-forecast/ontario/markham

I have tried scraping the value using `soup.find`, however, I am unsure if the parameters are correct. I am trying to obtain the value 17 from the code below:

```
<div class="info">
<div class="temp">17</div>
<div class="stackunits">
<div>
<span class="unitwrap">°C</span>
</div>
<div class="feels-like">
<span class="label">Feels like</span>
<span class="value">17</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify url
quote_page = 'https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/hourly-weather-forecast/ontario/markham'

# query website and return html to the variable 'page'
page = urlopen(quote_page)

# parse html using BeautifulSoup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# take out the <div> of temp and get its value
atemp_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'temp'})
atemp = atemp_box.text
print(atemp)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: What result do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same end point, an API, the page is using to get that info

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.theweathernetwork.com/api/data/caon0409/hourly/cm?ts=1632').json()
```

temperature is then

```
r['obs']['t']
```

There's lots of info returned. Explore response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=146a52e0a54f41fba56e2b788c47661a). For example, you can find the short term forecasts within:

```
r['sterm']['periods']
```